# Prevent changing datetime-local input in html

Tags: html, date, input, time, user-input

I am using this code to take input for date time.
It gives a good way to choose the date time. However the time dropdown(hours and minutes) keeps changing(scrolling) by itself every second. Is there any way to stop it.

`<input class="form-control form-control-sm " type="datetime-local" name="start_point" id="start_point">`

I tried to search for a relevant answer. Probably I couldn't figure out a what keyword I should search for.
The MDN web doc says it may have issue on some browser. I have checked this on  Google Chrome 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Can you set a default value?